# Pool of custom objects - best way to keep connections active

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, connection-pooling

I need to redo a custom connection pool of objects.  The connection pool essentially is a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` of objects, each of which performs actions against a third-party server (Cognos).  Each object in the pool contains a token (`String`) which is used to send requests to the third-party server.  The third-party server will expire a token after 60 minutes of inactivity.  I need to keep the token from expiring because creating a connection from scratch with the third-party server can take several seconds.  I found a way to keep the tokens from expiring, but I don't know how to incorporate this into an open-source connection pool solution like C3PO or BoneCP.  Or whether this "keep alive" logic should be performed outside of the pool, or within each object itself.

Does it make sense to have a timer within each connection object that will do the logic that keeps the token active (say every 10 minutes)?

Comment: I think you have two possibilities:
1. As you mentioned add the logic for refresh to the connection object and send some traffic every 10-20 minutes
2. Use your own pooling system and in a separate thread "refresh" all inactive connections from the link queue

Comment: I'd like for the object to be able to reinitialize the token as part of normal processing, in case something happens to the third-party server before the timer goes off.  If I add the logic for refresh to the connection object itself, how would I handle the object reinitializing the token via the timer, and the object reinitializing the token as part of normal processing?  Would I put 'synchronized' on the method that updates the token?

Comment: Yes, the synchronized on that method would prevent it to be executed concurrently. Of course you must then also make sure it does not interact with normal requests.
You should have a flag indicating if a normal request is currently active on this connection (then you can ignore the refresh request)